# How can I override ML_COMMENT in Xtext?

Tags: grammar, xtext

In Xtext 2.0, `ML_COMMENT` is defined in `org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals` as `hidden`.

I want to see comments in my grammar.

How can I undo this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just override the `hidden` statement from the inherited grammar:

```
grammar org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDsl 
with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals
hidden(WS, SL_COMMENT)  // <--- Override
```